# Should I run the training process serially or parallelly?

Tags: gpu, process

I have 21 ANN training processes to run.

I have four computers in my hand. Three of them are equipped with GPUs (two GPUs each).

The computers with GPUs don't allow me to run more than three processes simultaneously. GPUs can't accommodate more than three processes in the memory. As a result, if I run more than three processes, one or more processes get killed automatically.

What would be the best way to run processes to active the training in the least amount of time?

Comment: There is now an AI Community https://ai.stackexchange.com/ currently in beta: you might get the best answers there

Comment: @1NN, I know. That site is very slow in response.

Comment: @user366312 It may be slow, but it is the best fit

Comment: OK I saw now that you asked that question there, too. You might want to consider to [merge your accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) in order to get a better overall experience on all stack overflow communities. For example, I would have seen that you have an account over there, too.